# spatie/laravel-backup notifications not posting

Tags: laravel-5, notifications, backup, slack

*Using Laravel 5.3 and v4 from spatie/laravel-backup package.*

I am using [this package](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup) from Spatie which allows me to take backups using a simple terminal command. It is pretty straight forward to set up and when I run the command the backup runs as intended.

But there is also an option in the config file to set notifications (send mail, post to slack, ...) after a backup. This does not seem to do anything for me. I neither receive mails (and I have set my mailaddress) or see posts to my dedicated slack channel (and i have added the webhook).

I have already included the following composer packages since researching this problem:

- Guzzlehttp/guzzle
- maknz/slack-laravel
- maknz/slack

This is the simple notifications section in the config file:

```
'notifications' => [

    'notifications' => [
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupHasFailed::class         => ['mail'],
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\UnhealthyBackupWasFound::class => ['mail'],
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupHasFailed::class        => ['mail'],
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\BackupWasSuccessful::class     => ['mail'],
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\HealthyBackupWasFound::class   => ['mail'],
        \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifications\CleanupWasSuccessful::class    => ['mail'],
    ],

    /*
     * Here you can specify the notifiable to which the notifications should be sent. The default
     * notifiable will use the variables specified in this config file.
     */
    'notifiable' => \Spatie\Backup\Notifications\Notifiable::class,

    'mail' => [
        'to' => 'nicolas@******.***',
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'webhook_url' => 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/*****/*****/*************',
    ],
],
```

---

Not really sure if I am forgetting something? Thanks for the help

**The output I get in terminal after running the commands: [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/c7e57de4e7028eeb67c2af1445f6f58d)**

Extra: 
[This](https://youtu.be/fORNQ06K8LY?t=24m10s) is a talk at Laracon EU 2016, where the creator (Freek) shows off his package.

Comment: did you configure your mail setting in order to send mails.

Comment: Yep, all other mails functions are working.

Comment: What output you get when you run `php artisan backup:run`

Comment: Sorry, seems like I forgot to post this... https://gist.github.com/NicolasVanhecke/c7e57de4e7028eeb67c2af1445f6f58d